# Visualization of freqency data

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

Does any one know a great way to display the frequency of data  for different table where the tables have missing values.

Take an Example

```
Table A                             Table B                          Table C
List  | Freq                         List  | Freq                      List  | Freq
1        10                           2       29                        3       10
2.5      300                          2.5     16                        3.5     120
3.5      100                          3       100                       4      100
```

How best can I visualize this data such that I can see comparison between the tabel. The histogram is not cutting it for me because of the bin thing.

Comment: What do you mean by `visualize`? Is the bin size the same for all tables? Why is there a duplicate `3` in `Table C`? What kind of display would you like (table, graph, text)?

Comment: sorry it was hypothetical data which mimics my original data that and I made a mistake while typing I have corrected the 3. I am looking to see more of a graphical relationship. The bin size fluctuates for some of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look as usual plot in parametric form, i.e. defined by 2 arrays {x[i],y[i]}. In yours case x[i] can be "List", y[i] can be "Freq". For particular plot I can recommend [Stem plot](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_90.html#Stem-sample). In [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net) (GPL plotting library) you can call Stem(x,y,stl); several times for each table and change style for each of them (like, stl="bx", "ro", "gs" -- blue x, red circle, green square and so on, see [MathGL line styles](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_5.html#Line-styles)).